# C# Enum With Number Value, Reading That Value as String?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum list with assigned int values, if I understand correct. I need to keep the leading 0 so is there a way to consider this value a string and not an int?

My enums

```
    public enum CsvRowFormat
    {
        BeginningOfFile = 01,
        School = 02,
        Student = 03,
        EndOfFile = 04
    }
```

Currently I'm reading out the value like this which I find inefficient

```
studentRowFormat.AppendFormat("0{0}",(int)TransactionFile.CsvRowFormat.Student).ToString();
```

Comment: "0" + (int)TransactionFile.CsvRowFormat.Student

Comment: @kenny He already said that's what he's using.

Comment: Have a look at the [standard number formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). If you used `{0:D2}` that would output any 1 digit value with a leading zero.

Comment: @Servy actually he's using a Format() rather than concatenating

Comment: @kenny Which is *exactly* what the format is going to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `"{0:D2}"` as the format string.  It will pad the string with leading zeros until it is of length 2.

The `enum` you are using is just storing the numeric value of what you are assigning, not the string value, so it doesn't retain knowledge of the fact that you supplied a leading zero.  Native `enum` types cannot be backed by a string; they must be backed by an integer value.  You can create your own custom type that "looks" like it's a string-backed enum, but using such a solution will be much more effort than just using a more proper format string with your existing integer `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

Int32 has [a ToString() that takes a format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y.aspx). So the easiest way is something like this:

```
studentRowFormat.Append(((int)TransactionFile.CsvRowFormat.Student).ToString("D2"));
```

You don't need the leading 0 in the enum declarations.

Comment: You can use the number format in the format string, rather than using the `ToString` on the `int`.

Comment: You sure can, but I find that lots of people don't know about the formatable ToString() and I figured someone else would expand on the AppendFormat() approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to consider the value as a string instead of an int.  See [C# Enum Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  You could use the formatting options provided by the other answers, or you could write a struct that would allow your code to be much cleaner.  Because I don't know your reasons for using an enum, I feel I must point out that structs have some behavioral differences.  Here is an example of using a struct for this solution:

```
public struct CsvRowFormat
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    private CsvRowFormat(string value) : this()
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static BeginningOfFile { get { return new CsvRowFormat("01"); } }
    public static School { get { return new CsvRowFormat("02"); } }
    public static Student { get { return new CsvRowFormat("03"); } }
    public static EndOfFile { get { return new CsvRowFormat("04"); } }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
studentRowFormat.Append(TransactionFile.CsvRowFormat.Student);
```

Hope this helps!